# If div contains something change css of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having html like this:

```
<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)">
    <div class="ProizvodInner">
        <p class="KatBr">10-56 L   </p>
        <p class="Naziv">TN 35  SRAF  1000/1 </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)">
    <div class="ProizvodInner">
        <p class="KatBr">10-88 L   </p>
        <p class="Naziv">TN 70  SRAF  1000/1 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have `input` element with `onclick` method that runs function which should do this:

- Check if any HTML part inside div with class `Proizvod` contains input and if it is then change css of that div with class `Proizvod`.

So let's say I typed in `88` and it goes

```
<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)"> /* There is no html part here - skip */
    <div class="ProizvodInner"> /* There is no html part here - skip */
        <p class="KatBr">10-56 L   </p> /* There is html part here - it doesn't contain 88 - skip*/
        <p class="Naziv">TN 35  SRAF  1000/1 </p> /* There is html part here - it doesn't contain 88 - skip*/
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)"> /* There is no html part here - skip */
    <div class="ProizvodInner"> /* There is no html part here - skip */
        <p class="KatBr">10-88 L   </p> /* There is html part here - it does contain 88 - change this div with class Proizvod display to none */

        <p class="Naziv">TN 70  SRAF  1000/1 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
function Filter(element)
{
    $t = $(element).val();
    $("div:contains($t)").css( "display", "none" );
}
```

But nothing happens nor error appear.

Comment: A `div` cannot have a `value` attribute. Reading the value using jQuery is wrong.

Comment: You need to store all the elements inside that div class in array and iterate over it's text and find if text is present or not based on regex or js include method.

Comment: I don't understand where you type the 88 and you want to hide the things that contain the thing you type - wouldn't you want to filter to show the things that you type?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy officially no, but `$(element).attr("value")` would work, just like any other arbitrary attribute you might wish to define on an element. `.val()` reads the value _property_ not the _attribute_. And divs certainly don't have that.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy anyway, OP is not trying to read the value of the div using the posted code.

Comment: @ADyson yes I know that, I was pointing to that not OP's original problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$t` is meaningless inside your selector string like that, it's just treated like a a literal string. There's no string interpolation in JS like in languages like PHP which would place its value into the final string.

Try `$("div:contains(" + $t + ")")` instead.

Also your code currently targets all divs, not just the ones with the class "Proizvod" as mentioned in the question.

Here's a demo which fixes both of the above issues, and also resets the filter each time so that results hidden by the previous filter operation are visible again:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#FilterButton").click(function() {
    $t = $("#Filter").val();
    $(".Proizvod").css("display", "block"); //reset previous filter
    $(".Proizvod:contains(" + $t + ")").css("display", "none"); //apply new filter
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)">
  <div class="ProizvodInner">
    <p class="KatBr">10-56 L </p>
    <p class="Naziv">TN 35 SRAF 1000/1 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Proizvod" value="131" onclick="IdiNaProizvod(this)">
  <div class="ProizvodInner">
    <p class="KatBr">10-88 L </p>
    <p class="Naziv">TN 70 SRAF 1000/1 </p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="Filter" /><button type="button" id="FilterButton">Filter</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you want to make that syntax work

```
$(`div:contains(${$t})`).css( "display", "none" );
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with selection of the div

You need to apply `$("div:contains(" + $t + ")")` for `contains` check.

Please check below code, I removed some extra code, and apply class border so you can get more idea.

```js
function Filter() {
    $("body > div").removeClass('YesProizvod').addClass('Proizvod');//this is for reset all

    $t = $('#myFilter').val();
    $("body > div:contains(" + $t + ")").removeClass('Proizvod').addClass('YesProizvod');
}
```

```css
.Proizvod {
    border: solid 2px green;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.YesProizvod {
    border: solid 2px red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myFilter" value="88" />
<button onclick="Filter()">Click here to filter</button>
<br><br>
<div class="Proizvod" value="131">
    <div class="ProizvodInner">
        <p class="KatBr">10-56 L   </p>
        <p class="Naziv">TN 35  SRAF  1000/1 </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Proizvod" value="131">
    <div class="ProizvodInner">
        <p class="KatBr">10-88 L   </p>
        <p class="Naziv">TN 70  SRAF  1000/1 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will be helpful.